# 18.04 can't boot using Xorg, only Wayland

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 18.04

I recently updated to 18.04 and cannot boot using Xorg only Wayland. I have tried reinstalling xorg, reinstalling nvidia drivers, setting `WaylandEnable=false`  in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` but whenever trying to login using Xorg I get a frozen screen and mouse. I am using the latest nvidia-390 driver. My laptop has a dual graphics card ie. Intel and Nvidia. I would be fine staying with Wayland however it seems unstable and a dual monitor setup isn't working. Any thoughts what I can do to get this working so I can use Xorg .

Answer (score 1):

You can try to inspect `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

I also had this issue. In my case, the reason was a corrupt file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` which had the following line:

`Example # xorg.conf.d que snippet assigns the touchpad driver`

which was supposed to be:

`# Example xorg.conf...`

Comment: what were the symptoms (logs etc.) that lead you to where to look for the error?

Comment: I don't remember. That was 1.5 year ago. But I guess I found some clues in Xorg.0.log.

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled with 19.04. After disabling Nouveau at boot, the installer correctly installed an NVidia driver and now everything works.